# Getting last row in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find

I am using find() function in mongodb and got a record in following format

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 52a561ea78e9288b568b4567
        )

    [friendID] => 1
    [name] => Shobhit Srivastav
    [senderID] => 2
    [receiverID] => 1386570218
    [receiverType] => TW
    [receiverUserID] => 3
    [status] => 0
)

Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 52a5623178e928d8568b4567
        )

    [friendID] => 2
    [name] => Sachin Tendulkar
    [senderID] => 2
    [receiverID] => 1386570289
    [receiverType] => TW
    [receiverUserID] => 3
    [status] => 0
)
```

but I want record of last row which are inserted in the table. how can I find??

**Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: Show normal mondodb output, not your php's print_r

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get last record inserted in the table, then sort by [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) in descending order:

> sorting on an _id field that stores ObjectId values is roughly
>   equivalent to sorting by creation time.

and get first record:

```
db.collection.find().sort( { _id : -1 } ).limit(1);
```

With php driver it will look like

```
$doc = $collection->find()->sort(array("_id" => -1))->limit(1)->getNext();
```

Comment: Adding an update to the search query : `db.collection.findOne().sort( { _id : -1 } );`